# Swift: 'NSLayoutFormatOptions' does not have a member named 'Element'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, view

I am getting a "'NSLayoutFormatOptions' does not have a member named 'Element'" error in my ViewController.swift class and cannot find a solution. Here is some of the code:

```
var views: [NSObject: AnyObject] = [:]

var error = Piechart.Slice(color: UIColor.magentaColor(), value: 4, text: "Zero")

var zero = Piechart.Slice(color: UIColor.magentaColor(), value: 15, text: "Zero")

var win = Piechart.Slice(color: UIColor.orangeColor(), value: 10, text: "Winner")

let piechart = Piechart()
piechart.delegate = self
piechart.title = "Service"
piechart.activeSlice = 2
piechart.layer.borderWidth = 1
piechart.slices = [error, zero, win]

piechart.autoresizesSubviews = false
view.addSubview(piechart)
views["piechart"] = piechart

view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[piechart]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))

view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-200-[piechart(==200)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
```

Xcode gives the error on the bottom two lines of code. Can anyone offer any guidance? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using: `var views: [String: AnyObject]`? And do you really need views to be a class property? If not, then you can just do: `let views = ["piechart": piechart]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it helps to change `options: []` to `options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0)`